# Replace full URL With DE Attribute in Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have a data extension with a filed called 'SaveDesignLink' that is the full URL I want to populate. Say the URL is: www.test.com

Here is my current code in the email:

```
< a href="%%SaveDesignLink%%" style="color: #000000;"><img style="display:block; border:none" src="%%Image%%" border="0" alt="Complete Your %%Product%%!" width="600"></a>
```

But when I test it the link comes back with a 404 Error and goes to: click.email.site.com/www.test.com

The Data Extension is both Sendable and Testable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is that you need to wrap the RedirectTo function around your personalization string.

Just like `%%=RedirectTo(SaveDesignLink)=%%.`

But i encourage you that you save your dataextension value to a variable before using it. Another best practise is that you declare and set most of the variables on top of the template or something like that. This way you always know which variables are used in that template / email and can adjust/make changes fast.

For example:

```
var @save_design_link
set @save_design_link = [SaveDesignLink]
%%=RedirectTo(@save_design_link)=%%
```

Or for more stability/robustness like [**Lukas Lunow**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/36623/lukas-lunow) stated in the comment:

```
var @save_design_link
set @save_design_link = AttributeValue("SaveDesignLink")
%%=RedirectTo(@save_design_link)=%%
```

This makes checks like IF Empty(@save_design_link) possible and furthermore makes you feel safer ;) **Better Safe than Sorry.**

Which would result in this:

```
var @save_design_link
set @save_design_link = AttributeValue("SaveDesignLink")
< a href="%%=RedirectTo(@save_design_link)=%%" style="color: #000000;"><img style="display:block; border:none" src="%%Image%%" border="0" alt="Complete Your %%Product%%!" width="600"></a>
```

Comment: I will suggest, for robustness, always using AttributeValue to fetch a field from a sendable DE: *set @SaveDesignLink = AttributeValue("SaveDesignLink")*

Comment: As Lukas said, its better to do it with attributeValue, but for anyone who uses CloudPages here is a useful question / answer [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285461/clarification-attributevalue-with-cloudpagesurl)

Comment: I tried the code exactly as you said and I'm getting the same error and link issue.

Comment: Can you try to just print out the link next to your Image or after it? Just Write `%%=v(@save_design_link)=%%` and watch it ? Or make a link only without the Image? The error should not appear

Comment: Figured it out - I needed to add https:// to the beginning of the link (even though the link in the DE included that). Not sure why but seems to be working correctly now.

Comment: Weird, I have some of this stuff running and i did not have to include a Double https://. You really had to write a concat in front of this URL String to prepend https://? Or what did you exactly do. We want to learn from mistakes or unexpected behaviour. It would be great if you show your Solution in a comment