# Marketing Cloud Attribute Value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Having trouble understanding AttributeValue and have few questions:

1. Is this like system attributes? Different to the Attribute and Attribute Groups you set in Contact Builder? i.e. Adding new attribute values per subscriber in Email Studio, subscriber properties?

I tried `AttributeGroup("emailaddr")`  which shows the email address but when I try `AttributeGroup("postcode")` nothing populates.

2. The definition I have found online states, the attribute values can include the following data sources:

- Email Subscriber Profile Attributes
- Sendable Data Extension Fields
- Journey Builder Entry Source Attributes
- MobileConnect List Attributes
- MobilePush Attributes

Could I get explannation on how it would use "Journey Builder Entry Source Attribute" - Does this just mean the fields in the Data Extension? whether the source is Data Extension, or API...?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You would use this function to pull a value from a Data Extension, a personalization string or a profile attribute. You use it to pull a value into your AMPscript for further processing in the script. You cannot use it to „add” a new attribute to the data structure.

Comment: Please search on this platform for similar questions: [AttributeValue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=AttributeValue), one particular [Thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285461/clarification-attributevalue-with-cloudpagesurl)

Answer (score 1):

As zuzannamj said, its something that you want to use as a starting point. Attributevalue pulls a value from a Data Extension, a personalization string or a profile attribute. You can find out system defined values here.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5